# Variable is undefined inside if statement

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve an algorithm "Seach and Replace" which states:

> Perform a search and replace on the sentence using the arguments
>   provided and return the new sentence.
>
> First argument is the sentence to perform the search and replace on.
>
> Second argument is the word that you will be replacing (before).
>
> Third argument is what you will be replacing the second argument with
>   (after).
>
> NOTE: Preserve the case of the original word when you are replacing
>   it. For example if you mean to replace the word "Book" with the word
>   "dog", it should be replaced as "Dog"

So i'm trying to pass a test when original word is uppercased, so replaced word also gets uppercased. But my variable inside if statement is undefined. Please explain me! My code is following:

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  var newString = str.replace(before, after);
  if (before[0]===before[0].toUpperCase) {
    var capWord = after[0].toUpperCase+after(1);
    console.log(capWord);
    newString = str.replace(before, capWord);
    return newString;
  }
  return newString;
}

myReplace("He is Sleeping on the couch", "Sleeping", "sitting");
```

Capword is undefined, why? And how can i bypass this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You're missing something: toUpperCase => toUpperCase()

Comment: I don't get that result when I run your code.  I get "He is sitting on the couch".

Comment: `+after(1);` should be `+after[1];`... This is a small typographical error imo and I am voting to close as such.

Comment: Preserving case should not just be for the first letter. If you replace `BOOK` with `dog` the result should be `DOG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It will be toUpperCase() - Converts to upper case. Its a function and hence needs to be invoked.
- after.substring(1) - Extract the substring as it is after the first letter.

```js
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  var newString = str.replace(before, after);
  if (before[0]===before[0].toUpperCase()) {
    var capWord = after[0].toUpperCase()+after.substring(1);
    newString = str.replace(before, capWord);
    return newString;
  }
  return newString;
}

console.log(myReplace("He is Sleeping on the couch", "Sleeping", "sitting"));
```